# Proof that the multiplication of a group is recovered by the repeated 2-pullback of the unique point of its delooping

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, 2-categories

Given a group $G$ with delooping $BG$, $BG$ has a unique point $\iota:\star\rightarrow BG$ and $G$ is equivalent to the 2-pullack of $\iota$ along itself. Furthermore, the repeated 2-pullback $\iota\times_{BG} \iota \times_{BG} \iota$ is equivalent to $G\times G$ and comes with two morphisms $\tau_1,\tau_2:G\times G\rightarrow G$ such that, up to equivalence, $\tau_1$ can be identified with a projection and $\tau_2$ with the group multiplication, and this part is making me problems. I know this is common folklore and has already been vastly generalized, but I couldn't find a proof of it, particularly in the setting of (weak) 2-categories. I get the intuition, that, for a tuple $(g,h)$, if $\tau_1(g,h)= g$ then $\tau_2(g,h)$ has to be related to $g$ by composition with $h$ in $BG$, but I feel like I really need to stare at a proof of it to get familiar with the technical details.

Does anyone have a reference or could write down the proof?

Comment: Write down a model for the iterated pullback, as concretely as possible. The answer will be there.

Comment: @ZhenLin Well, I tried calculating $(\iota\times_{BG} \iota)\times_{BG} \iota \simeq G \times_{BG} \iota$, and since $G$ is a set, so a disjoint union of objects, the pullback can be computed pointwise and is over each object of $G$ equivalent to $\iota\times_{BG} \iota$, so it immediately follows that the pullback is equivalent to $G\times G$ and we get two morphisms, one to $G$ which is a projection, and one to the terminal object, the domain of $\iota$. But I still don't see where the second morphism to $G$ comes from.

Comment: OK, maybe that was too concrete... maybe it would be better to consider a slightly more abstract situation, where you have a diagram $\bullet \rightarrow \bullet \leftarrow \bullet \rightarrow \bullet \leftarrow \bullet$ and want to take the limit of this (in the bicategorical sense).

Comment: @ZhenLin I felt stuck, so I asked a friend, but he confused me all the more! In particular, he pointed out that a cone over the diagram $\star\rightarrow BG \leftarrow\star$ should consist of three morphisms, it's just that the morphism into $BG$ usually isn't drawn since it is the composition of the other two. But if we take the weak limit, shouldn't this third morphism only be naturally isomorphic to the other two? So wouldn't we have to split the pullback diagram in the middle, with two natural transformations, one left and one right? I said that this couldn't be true, but I don't know why!

Comment: Your friend is correct. However, this is not an important detail. In practice you can assume that one of the two 2-cells is trivial/degenerate.

Comment: @ZhenLin We see now how we can apply a natural transformation to the middle functor to trivialize one half of the pullback. But can we get another hint for the multiplication morphism? We seem stuck. We see that the limit of the zick-zack diagram you mentioned factors through $G$ in two ways, we can't get actual description? A point in the limit corresponds to two transformations, one for each cospan, given by elements of $G$, but it would seem that the morphisms into $G$ we get by restricting the cone to one cospan were the elements that mark the transformations. Why isn't it two projections?

Comment: When you have a diagram $A \rightarrow B \leftarrow C \rightarrow D \leftarrow E$, the limit is (equivalent to) the category whose objects are $(a, c, e, b, d)$ where $a, c, e$ are objects in $A, C, E$ (resp.), $b$ is a morphism in $B$ from the image of $a$ to the image of $c$, and $d$ is a morphism in $D$ from the image of $c$ to the image of $e$. In your case, $B = D = \mathrm{B} G$, $A = C = E = 1$,  and $C \to B$ and $C \to D$ are identical. So we can paste the 2-cells along their common boundary. etc. It is probably better to work it out yourself.